# Vine API - User Data based on Anchor

Tags: api, twitter, social-networking, vine

Twitter API, they have since_id.  Instagram API, they have min_id.  I am trying to see if anyone knows how to use "anchors" in the Vine API to achieve the same effect of only pull new user data based off another post ID as a reference point.  I have searched and searched, and the few folks who have tried to document the Vine API, didn't have the parameter information.